# CSS transition causing issue with function

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have a panel in my AngularJS App, with a dynamic title, depending on which item from the list a user clicked. If the user clicks the list item labelled `Green`, green would display in the title, like so:

```
<p>{{$ctrl.colourPhaseTitle.title}} Phase</p> // DYNAMIC TITLE

<li class="bg-phase-green pill-tabs" ng-init="$ctrl.colourKey(0);" ng-click="activeTab = 0; $ctrl.colourKey(0);" ng-hide="activeTab == 0">Green</li>
<li class="bg-phase-amber pill-tabs" ng-click="activeTab = 1; $ctrl.colourKey(1)" ng-hide="activeTab == 1">Amber</li>

//activeTab with the `ng-click` along with `ng-hide/ng-show` is what hides/show li elements
```

The `colourKey` is a function in the controller which display specific information such as a title and a description, and the `activeTab` is what hides the `li` item when the user has clicked it.

It works/worked. Before adding a `:hover` transition, the displaying and hiding of the `li` items ran smoothly. Now there is a `.2s` transition on properties such as the `background`, the `li` items will flicker, instead of instantly swapping.

***Question***

How do I wait for the CSS transition to end, before executing the function for the items to swap (`show/hide`)

```
.notification-tabs .pill-tabs {
    -webkit-transition: background .2s ease-in-out, border .2s ease-in-out, color .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background .2s ease-in-out, border .2s ease-in-out, color .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: background .2s ease-in-out, border .2s ease-in-out, color .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: If you could provide a quick codepen so that we could see what you exactly means it would be easier. I do believe that you could use keyframes for that purpose but I'm not really sure on what's the issue and what you want to achieve

Comment: If you are show/hide in jQuery you can **$(element).delay(2000).show()/hide()** to wait 2 secs